# how can I compare several groups within samples and between samples

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

I have a clinical data,

3 control (replicated)
3 Treated A (replicate)
3 Treated B (replicate)

-I want to know how these treated are different from each other and from the control. 
- I want to know which sample is statistically different from the rest

I want to do this in R

```
data <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 2L), .Label = c("Mol1", "Mol10", "Mol2", "Mol3", "Mol4", 
"Mol5", "Mol6", "Mol7", "Mol8", "Mol9"), class = "factor"), Control1 = c(0.00505, 
0.00136, 0.000121, 0.00109, 0.000328, 0.000552, 0.0221, 0.00393, 
0.00164, 6.72e-05), Control2 = c(0.00384, 0.00178, 6.18e-05, 
0.0011, 0.000479, 0.000537, 0.0251, 0.0039, 0.00153, 6.3e-05), 
    Control3 = c(0.00421, 0.00143, 0.000121, 0.000901, 0.000283, 
    0.000393, 0.0287, 0.00365, 0.00148, 4.93e-05), TreatA1 = c(0.0101, 
    0.00137, 1e-04, 0.000917, 0.000228, 0.000667, 0.0376, 0.000504, 
    0.00114, 0.000114), TreatA2 = c(0.00326, 0.00173, 9.35e-05, 
    0.00103, 0.000389, 0.000376, 0.0342, 0.0015, 0.00164, 0.000129
    ), TreatA3 = c(0.00506, 0.00124, 9.44e-05, 0.000701, 0.000326, 
    0.000358, 0.0326, 0.00114, 0.00129, 0.000123), TreatB1 = c(0.00432, 
    0.00282, 6.77e-06, 0.00132, 0.000335, 0.000435, 0.0347, 0.0014, 
    0.00125, 0.000271), TreatB2 = c(0.00195, 0.00231, 9.03e-06, 
    0.00116, 0.000401, 0.000674, 0.0391, 0.00194, 0.00191, 0.00014
    ), TreatB3 = c(0.00167, 0.00209, 5.98e-06, 0.00101, 0.000216, 
    0.000713, 0.0279, 0.000506, 0.00137, 0.000144)), .Names = c("X", 
"Control1", "Control2", "Control3", "TreatA1", "TreatA2", "TreatA3", 
"TreatB1", "TreatB2", "TreatB3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: So you have 9 groups and you want to compare all of them with each other?  Do you need all these $9\cdot 8 / 2 = 36$ pairwise comparisons?  In this case you can just compare all groups pairwise with, say, $t$-test.

Comment: @Ott Toomet  They are replicate, I don't know whether I should get average of them or I should count them as a separate group! please give me your advise

Comment: Maybe I miss something obvious but what is your aim?  I suspect you want to a) test if treatment A != control; b) test if treatment B != control; c) test if treatment A != treatment B; d) test if all three replicas are the same across all treatment types.  However, you may not be interested if treatment A replica 2 is equal to treatment B replica 1?

Comment: @Ott Toomet  Yes you got it, this is what I want to do

Comment: If this is the case, you can just resort to pairwise comparisons.  If you are happy with just comparing the means (small sample/medical data suggests you may) then you can use $t$-test, or I would go rather for regression analysis (ie do a bunch of $t$-tests in bulk.)  Are the 'mol1' -- 'mol9' different observations (individuals?)

Comment: @Ott Toomet  please go ahead and give me your solution. I will definitely accept if it sounds statistically